# How to split TextArea Input at every line break PHP

Tags: php, line-breaks, htmlspecialchars

i have some trouble splitting my TextArea Input at every linebreak:
If I insert this text:

```
"Hello:
 world"
```

Then I have this string as my value
`Hello: world`

I tried something like

```
$input = str_replace(" ", "", $input);
```

OR

```
$input = trim($input);
```

But nothing changes.
I want to remove all the linebreaks because later when I output the string with htmlspecialchars it fills the line breaks with something like `"&#13;&#10;&#13;&#"`;
And I want to remove it.
So I thought i can split the string and after that, add it up together so all my linebreaks will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$input = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], '', $input);
```

Or

```
preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $input);
```

Comment: I also tried it but its the same result :/

Comment: What do you mean? Are you sure follow it? Check my demo  https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/qak0m?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=